# minizinc search consecutive numbers in array

Tags: arrays, numbers, minizinc

i am trying to make a model in minizinc that finds 3 numbers in sequence with the MaxSUM, in arrays below:

```
[2,3,4,**10,22,11**,17]).
[1,2,3,4,**10,22,11**,11,10,24]).
[2,3,4,5,10,23,**10,22,11**,17]).
```

I want my model to output these numbers, their indices and their sum.

I tried this:

```
array[int] of int : list1 = [2,3,4,10,22,11,17]; 
array[int] of int : list2 = [1,2,3,4,10,22,11,11,10,24]; 
array[int] of int : list3 = [2,3,4,5,10,23,10,22,11,17];

array[1..3] of var int: values;
array[1..3] of var int: indices;

constraint forall(i in 1..3, j in list1)(
                     values[i]=list1[j]
                  );
constraint exists (i in 1..length(list1)-2)(
                       exists(j in 1..length(list2)-2)(
                       exists(k in 1..length(list3)-2)
                             (list1[i]=list2[j]/\list2[j]=list3[k] /\
                             list1[i+1]=list2[j+1]/\list2[j+1]=list3[k+1]/\
                             list1[i+2]=list2[j+2]/\list2[j+2]=list3[k+2]
                             /\values[1]=list1[i]/\values[2]=list1[i+1]/\values[3]=list1[i+2]
                             /\indices[1]=i/\indices[2]=j/\indices[3]=k
                  )));
var int: max_sum;
constraint max_sum=sum(values);
solve maximize max_sum;
```

but, UNSATISFIABLE :(

Comment: You should provide clear information about what you expect and what you receive for this moment. Please consider editing the question.

Comment: of course... 
i'm receiving this:

  WARNING: model inconsistency detected
C:/Users/�������/Desktop/�������� ��������/bebee.mzn:8:
  in call 'forall'
  in array comprehension expression
    with i = 1
    with j = 3
C:/Users/�������/Desktop/�������� ��������/bebee.mzn:9:
  in binary '=' operator expression
Running bebee.mzn
=====UNSATISFIABLE=====
Finished in 77msec

i expect this:


values = [10, 22, 11];
indices = [4, 5, 7];
sum = 43;
----------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two hints.

Hint 1: The error states that there's something wrong at line 8, where j=3. If you comment out this constraint then there's no syntax error. Since I don't understand the purpose of this constraint I can't help you there.

Hint 2: Also, if you comment out that constraint (at line 8) then it might take a long time to get a solution - depending on the solver - since you have the decision variables `values` and `indices` set to `var int`. It's much better to state a positive domain for these two decision variables.